# How can I calculate the mean and standard deviation using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, mean, standard-deviation

I am using the `ukpolice` package.

Using the `dplyr` package, we had to create a new dataframe that consists of the mean and standard deviation per category per month (which is a columnn of an already established dataframe).

We did the following:

```
crimes_cat_calc <- crimes_cat_month %>%
 group_by(month) %>%
 summarize (mean=mean(number, na.rm=TRUE).
```

However, the new dataframe is not established. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that we can understand what the problem is?

Comment: What you did seems correct, except the period right at the end. Can you try to remove it? You can then add standard deviation in the same call. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just that you have small typos in your code. Can you try to copy-paste this:

```
crimes_cat_calc <- crimes_cat_month

crimes_cat_calc %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  summarize(mean=mean(number, na.rm=TRUE), standard_deviation=sd(number, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Don't put a period at the end. Don't put a space between summarize and the first parenthesis. Also don't forget to close the two parentheses in the summarize call. Finally note an indent is needed from second line.